# AJAX post call stores data twice in my JSON file

Tags: jquery, node.js, json, ajax

I stumbled across a problem in my project. I want to build a kind of archive for news articles using node.js. I store the input of a form (all the relevant data) into a JSON file. This is my form (simplified):

```
<form id="json-form">
<label class="json-form-labels" for="title">title</label>
<input id="json-form-title" type="text" name="title" required>

<label class="json-form-labels" for="date">date</label>
<input id="json-form-date" type="text" name="date" required>        

<label class="json-form-labels" for="author"><author</label>
<input id="json-form-author" type="text" name="author" required>

<label class="json-form-labels" for="topic">topic</label>
<select id="json-form-topic"name="topic">
    <option value="not_specified"></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<label class="json-form-labels" for="Link">link</label>
<input id="json-form-link" type="text" name="link" required>

<label class="json-form-labels" for="description">description</label>
<textarea name="" id="json-form-description-textarea" required>    </textarea>  

<label class="json-form-labels" for="content">content</label>
<textarea name="" id="json-form-content-textarea" required></textarea>

<button id="json-form-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On submit I am using AJAX to send the data:

```
$(function() {
$(document).on('click', '#json-form-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#json-form-submit').prop('disabled', true);
    var title = document.getElementById('json-form-title').value; 
    var author = document.getElementById('json-form-author').value; 
    var date = document.getElementById('json-form-date').value; 
    var topic = document.getElementById('json-form-topic').value; 
    var articlelink = document.getElementById('json-form-link').value; 
    var description = document.getElementById('json-form-description-textarea').value; 
    var content = document.getElementById('json-form-content-textarea').value; 
    var data = { title: title, author: author, date: date, related: related, articlelink: articlelink, description: description, content: content };
        
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: '/create-article',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function() {
            
        },
        error: function() {
            
        }
    });
});         
});
```

Server-side I am writing the data in my JSON like this:

```
app.post('/create-article', (req, res) => {
var title = req.body.title;
var date = req.body.date;
var author = req.body.author;
var topic = req.body.topic;
var articlelink = req.body.articlelink;
var description = req.body.description;
var content = req.body.content;

const data = { title: title, author: author, date: date, topic: topic, articlelink: articlelink, description: description, content: content };

const jsonString = fs.readFileSync('./public/files/js/articles.json');
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
jsonObject.push(data);
fs.writeFileSync('./public/files/js/articles.json', JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
})
```

The problem I'm facing now is that my the new article is written twice into my JSON file instead of once and I have honestly no clue why. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the browser network, check how many calls are going on submit, rightClick->inspect->network

Comment: As far as I can see it's only executed once

Comment: I'll give you simplified version of what you are doing to submit the data as an answer so at least you will see how to easily submit a form using AJAX. At least you will be sure the data is submitted once.

Comment: Add a console log inside the handler function and see if it gets called twice. If so you need to find out what causes the listener to be added twice such as loading the same script again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form submit might be securely simplified just to the following assuring only one submit. I'm not sure this will solve your issue, but at least you will be sure the form is submitted once and will learn how ot easily handle a form on AJAX submit.

**EDIT: Makes the JSON passed through the body.**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#json-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#json-form-submit').prop('disabled', true);
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var object = {};
    formData.forEach((value, key) => object[key] = value);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/create-article',
      contentType: false,
      data: JSON.stringify(object),
      processData: false,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('Success statusText =', response.statusText);
        $('#json-form-submit').prop('disabled', false);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log('Error statusText =', response.statusText);
        $('#json-form-submit').prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="json-form">
  <label class="json-form-labels" for="title">title</label>
  <input id="json-form-title" type="text" name="title" required>

  <label class="json-form-labels" for="date">date</label>
  <input id="json-form-date" type="text" name="date" required>

  <label class="json-form-labels" for="author"><author</label>
  <input id="json-form-author" type="text" name="author" required>

  <label class="json-form-labels" for="topic">topic</label>
  <select id="json-form-topic" name="topic">
    <option value="not_specified"></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>

  <label class="json-form-labels" for="Link">link</label>
  <input id="json-form-link" type="text" name="link" required>

  <label class="json-form-labels" for="description">description</label>
  <textarea name="" id="json-form-description-textarea" required>    </textarea>

  <label class="json-form-labels" for="content">content</label>
  <textarea name="" id="json-form-content-textarea" required></textarea>

  <button id="json-form-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How am I supposed to handle the data client-side, just req.body.data? So far I am getting a `Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0` error.

Comment: I didn't check what you are expecting server side, just a few moments and I'll make it compatible.

Comment: I've edited the answer above to support sending JSON in the body instead separate form entries.

Comment: At least you will know an easy and elegant way to handle a form submit. `FormData` well supported in modern browsers. You can check also how to append some extra fields not included in the form in case you may need this some day.

Comment: It's important to add `content-type: 'application/json'` to the ajax call, if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but aren't you reading the file and then pushing the data twice? NOTE: I'm just trying to help not much clue about this :)

```
const jsonString = fs.readFileSync('./public/files/js/articles.json');
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
jsonObject.push(data);
fs.writeFileSync('./public/files/js/articles.json', JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

Comment: I thought I was reading my file, putting it into a Json array and then push my existing object on it. I'm pretty confident that's not the issue but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Please look at you network tab in browser developer tools (Press F12) if the request is executed once.